# Where can I search for RHEL5 packages that yum search doesn't find?

Tags: rhel5, package-management

In this specific instance, I'm trying to find out if there is a package of the Apache Tomcat Native library available for RHEL5.  When I search on the web, I tend to find lots of package browsing sites that just aren't clear at all whether the package can be used on my RHEL5 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [DAG](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/)
- [pbone](http://rpm.pbone.net/)
- [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/)
- [Dries](http://dries.ulyssis.org/rpm/)
- [Livna](http://rpm.livna.org/)
- [RPMFusion](http://rpmfusion.org/)
- [RPMForge](https://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge)

You can add these repositories to your /etc/yum.conf, which will expand the repos that yum will check.  Beyond that, I wasn't able to find any pre-compiled RPMs for the native library... only a quick [howto article](http://i-proving.com/space/Barry+O%27Driscoll/blog/2008-09-16_1) on compiling & setting it up for RHEL 5.

Edit: 
The howto article is here: http://i-proving.com/space/Barry+O%27Driscoll/blog/2008-09-16_1

Comment: That blog link is double encoding the + to %2B which causes a 404 error.  The link was great though, thanks for digging it up!

Comment: Weird... in the edit page, the + isn't URL encoded and the link in the preview box works.  In the main question page, the + is URL encoded as %2B and breaks the link.  Wonder what I get for finding a bug in Serverfault? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm'
...
su -c 'yum install foo'
```

Comment: So are the rpms in this folder things that are properly built to work on RHEL5? That is where I always get confused and worried.  I figured they would be Fedora specific.

Comment: Yes, EPEL is built for RHEL. From the project web site (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL): "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) is a volunteer-based community effort from the Fedora project to create a repository of high-quality add-on packages for Red Hat Enterprise (RHEL) and its compatible spinoffs such as CentOS or Scientific Linux. Fedora is the upstream of RHEL and add-on packages for EPEL are sourced from the Fedora repository primarily and built against RHEL."

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the DAG repository? http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/

Answer (score 2):

These are the ones I often use are 'pbone' and 'freshrpms'. I'd suggest google-ing those as I can't post links yet :-P

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using RHEL, I would also caution that you are adding unsupported software. If you are tuning for top performance and absolutely need support, you should consider purchasing JBoss Enterprise Application Platform which includes tomcat-native. (And if you're just looking to save money, look at CentOS.)

Typically you can tell if an RPM was built for EL5 with a "el5" tag in the RPM name, i.e., tomcat-native-1.1.16-1.**el5**.i386.rpm

In my opinion EPEL is the safest route, read more about it at fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Dag/RPMForge also produce top quality builds. If you're new to this carefully read the website and test installs, some projects replace core OS components so make sure you're prepared.

Comment: Ugh.  I worked with JBoss for a while and it was so bloated for my tastes.  Slow to start up, difficult to sift through the hundreds of xml files looking for the right one to edit.  It is actually quite sad that I can say Tomcat is easier to manage. :)